# Block a row in sql after an update, and trigger a new update if necessary

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table in a postgresql database where there are 4 columns:

1. id (serial)
2. total (int)
3. done (int)
4. status (bool).

Now, I have some asyncronous processes that do some work and update this table. Basically, they add 1 to the done field, but I also want to update the status to True if total=done after upgrading done.

However, these processes can have the same id, and therefore I should block all the transaction (Update done, check done=total and update status if required) to avoid any problem. How can I do this?

I'm working with python3 and psycopg2.

Comment: If you are using v12 or greater the define status as a generated column.  `status boolean generated always as (total = done)`. But make sure none of your DML sets or inserts a value for `status`.

Comment: @Belayer I'll accept it as an answer if you post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using v12 or greater the define status as a generated column. status boolean generated always as (total = done). But make sure none of your DML sets or inserts a value for status

Comment: In postgresql v14 I had to add STORED at the end of your command https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html